# angular2+ how to load a sub module in routes from node_modules

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-routing, angular-router

as the title, I want to load a sub module([sub module link](https://github.com/dyh333/myNgModule)) from out-side project such as node_modules in routes([enter link description here](https://github.com/dyh333/useMyNgModule))

[image]

I have found this problem in stackoverflow and github and so on, but not found solution. anyone know it? thanks very much.

Comment: This is possible. Not sure if you provided wrong link or not,  but the link to your 'sub module' is a link to an angular project. Is this just an error ? Would be nice to see some code for the 'MyModule' and it's routingModule.

Answer (score 0):

From the above code snippet, You're trying to load your module as lazy loaded one.

1. 'MyModule' should be defined as **Feature module**
2. 'MyModule' **Should not import to any other module**
3. 'MyModule' module **route's comprised under a single route**

The above points are pre-requisites for lazy loading feature module.

Comment: hi, would you please show me some correct code for it? i tried but failed again and again...

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can use a path into loadChildren.

From [angular's documentation](https://angular.io/api/router/Routes)

```
[{
  path: 'team/:id',
  component: Team,
  loadChildren: 'team'
}]
```

> The router will use registered NgModuleFactoryLoader to fetch an
>   NgModule associated with 'team'. Then it will extract the set of
>   routes defined in that NgModule, and will transparently add those
>   routes to the main configuration.